# How to fix this django path without this prefix?

Tags: django

I made a simple blog and then i made a new app and copied all codes (changed to new apps) and i made url path. And all of them second app path doesn't work and it wants prefix...
Where is my fault?

Here is the github repo and also my codes here...
https://github.com/eseymenler/firmas

```
Ulus = folder name
Ulusal = project name
Ulusalb = First app
Firma = Second app
```

main project urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include('ulusalb.urls')),
    path("firma/", include('firma.urls')),
]
```

When i made this i have an error like this

[image]

but when i make this

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include('ulusalb.urls')),
    path("1/firma/", include('firma.urls')),
]
```

It works.

[image]

Why this happen?
I want url like this

```
path("firma/", include('firma.urls'))
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: Probably the `ulusalb.urls` contains a path that contains simply `<slug:slug>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the `ulusalb.urls` contains a path that contains simply `<slug:slug>`? This means that it will capture any slug (or string), including `firma`. What a slug does *not* capture is a slash, and therfore if you use a slash, it will continue looking for patterns and eventually fire `1/firma/`.

What you can do is put `firma/` first:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('firma/', include('firma.urls')),
    path('', include('ulusalb.urls')),
]
```

It will thus first look for patterns in `firma.urls` to match, and only if that fails, fallback on the `ulusalb.urls` patterns.

That being said, it might be better to make paths that do *not* overlap: imagine that you later have an object with `firma` as slug, then that object is not accessible, since `firma/` will fire first for `firma.urls`.

Comment: Thansk Willem Van Onsem, you solved my problem. I wanna make simple blog and business directory and i think this path listing enough for me but you taught me so much things.